# $div(t_{\nabla u})=\nabla div u$? In Navier Stoke Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

How to, in general prove, that:

**div($T_{\nabla u})=\nabla$div$u$**?

**$T$:the transpose.**

$u$: **is a function s.t** $(x,t) \rightarrow u(x,t):=x'(t)=(x_1'(t),...,x_n'(t))$

**is the velocity field of the fluid.**

**$\nabla$** :**nabla operator.**

**div**: **divergence.**

**In a reference, I have seen that:**

> 1)Tr(Du)=Tr∇u = divu ,
> 2)div(t∇u)=∇(divu)
> 3)div(2Du) = div(∇u +t∇u)=Δu +∇(divu)
> 4)div((div u)Id) = ∇(divu). ,Tr:trace,t:transpose.

**And point 2 is my question**(while divergenve gives a scalar, how might we apply a gradient on it! I am new to Navier Stokes equation lesson). And I need some help pls, or clarification.

Comment: Are you sure about this equation? I'm not really good at field theory, but divergence gives a scalar while gradient of divergence gives a vector.

Comment: @IPPK you can check my editing pls

Comment: Oh, it seems to be the divergence of a tensor field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A = (a_{ij})_{ij}$ then $\operatorname{div}(A)_i$ (that is, the $i$-th component of the vector $\operatorname{div}(A)$) is given by $$\sum_{j}\partial_j a_{ij}.$$

If $A = (\nabla u)^t$, that is, if $A$ is the transpose of $\nabla u$, then $a_{ij} = \partial_i u_j$ and therefore $$\operatorname{div}((\nabla u)^t)_i = \sum_{j}\partial_j\partial_iu_j.$$
On the other hand, since $\operatorname{div}u = \sum_j \partial_ju_j$, the $i$-th component of the vector $\nabla \operatorname{div}(u)$ is precisely $$\partial_i \operatorname{div}(u) = \partial_i \sum_j \partial_j u_j = \sum_j \partial_j\partial_i u_j.$$
Notice that in the very last step we have used Schwartz's theorem to swap the other of the derivatives. Hence these computations are rigorous if $u$ is sufficiently regular. Since you mention Navier-Stokes, chances are that you are working with different classes of functions. However, I hope this clarifies things a little bit!

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped! But I have a question, how can we define **div(A)** although $\nabla$ is a **column vector of size (n×1)** and **A is (n×n)** while **div(A):=$\nabla. A$**

Comment: @user854662: $\operatorname{div}(A)$ is also a column vector: it is defined as the column vector where the $i$-th entry is the divergence of the $i$-th row of $A$.

Comment: Sorry but can u explain it more? I am little confused, because I am new on this lesson... how can I multiply, as my first comment, while we have (n×1) times (n×n) matrix! Or can you explain it more pls..

Comment: @user854662: Sure. The divergence of a matrix $A$ is not defined as the inner product of $\nabla$ with the matrix $A$ (because, as you pointed out, just looking at the dimensions of these objects it wouldn't make sense). Instead, what you do is the following: you take the divergence of the rows of the matrix $A$ and use these scalars to form a vector. In other words, $div A$ is the vector where the first component is the divergence of the first row of $A$, the second component is the divergence of the second row of $A$, and so on.

Comment: thank you so much!!